# Request values from query string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

How could i extract House, Car, and Work value from this query string?

```
http://'mysite'/Result/Environments?House=1&Car=0&Work=1
```

Then assign values in LINQ statement below.

Action Method in Controller

```
public ActionResult Environments()
{
    //int totalSmokers = repository.Results.Where(x=>x.House = 
    return View();
}
```

Comment: HttpContext.Request.params also lets you access the query string as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have your `ActionResult` take them as parameters, like so (I'm assuming `bool`, if they're `int`, change them to `int`).

```
public ActionResult Environments(bool House, bool Car, bool Work)
```

Then you can use them in your LINQ statement, something like:

```
int totalSmokers = repository.Results
    .Where(x => x.House == House && x.Car == Car && x.Work == Work)
    .Count();
```

Even cleaner though, you could create a model (and return this in your view like you asked in comments), something like:

```
public class SmokersModel
{
    public bool House { get; set; }
    public bool Car { get; set; }
    public bool Work { get; set; }
    public int TotalSmokers { get; set; }
}
```

Then that tidies up your action method, you can do:

```
public ActionResult Environment(SmokersModel Model)
{
    Model.TotalSmokers = repository.Results
        .Where(x => x.House == Model.House && x.Car == Model.Car && x.Work == Model.Work)
        .Count();

    return View(Model);
}
```

Then change your view's model type to be `SmokersModel`:

```
@model SmokersModel
```

Comment: How would I make totalSmokers available to the view?

Comment: Change `return View()` to be `return View(totalSmokers)` and change your model type on your view to be an `int`.

Comment: @user2224493 Or you can use my updated 2nd example if you want to use a model.

Answer (score 1):

You can add parameters to your Action to retrieve the values passed in the query string.

```
public ActionResult Environments(int House, int Car, int Work)
      {
        //int totalSmokers = repository.Results.Where(x=>x.House == 
        return View();
      }
```

You can also get it using `Request["House"], Request["Car"] or Request["Work"]` inside your function.

Answer (score 1):

The following example writes the query `?House=1` to the console.

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri ("http://mysite.com/");
Uri myUri = new Uri (baseUri, "/Result/Environments?House=1&Car=0&Work=1");

Console.WriteLine(myUri.Query);
```

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can access these through `Request.QueryString`. There a couple ways to do this. The simplest is probably `Request.QueryString["House"]`, but keep in mind this will be a string. QueryString also has an `AllKeys` collection, so you can check that to see which values were actually provided.